# Product Variation as Thumbnail rather than Dropdown

Tags: commerce

I am wondering if someone has tackled having product variations as thumbnails rather than a dropdown option.

Have a look at this page: http://www.partytimerentals.com/catalog/product/basic-poly-rounds

You see that I have loads of variations for that particular table linen, but my end user has to look through a load of item options. I need a way to show them the associated swatch, and when they click load that variation. The same as now, just as I said, an image thumbnail rather than a select box.

Any direction on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a mockup of what I am looking for: http://cloud.um-me.com/0f1a2p1b1T0A

Aaron

Comment: That's a whole lot of options to show a thumbnail for all of them. Could you draw up a quick image/diagram for what you're after and edit the question to add this image?

Comment: Added a PDF link

Comment: Ah, when I see thumbnail I think bigger. IDK why since a thumbnail is small but I always think bigger. You're thinking more like your avatar picture here. I will look into it and post something later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom to module to handle this. I did a db_query to pull the attributes and thumbnails, and used jQuery to change the select menu upon clicking the image.

Answer (score 3):

Once i've got the same problem and I went through [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1180016) Here there are different solution and suggestion.

I was looking for a module who shows the color instead of text so I have chosen this module [Fancy Attribute](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fancy_attributes) . You can create a taxonomy with a field color and add the hex code of the color, then you can use it as a variation.

Comment: The module will also work with an image instead of a hex code, so it can be used for any kind of an attribute.