# Display product variations in table

Tags: commerce

There is currently a "product page" that contains combobox with the different variation values for that product category, but I'm curious if it's possible to add a table display to the product page to show all variations of that category within a table so a user can see what's available instead of manually drilling into every combobox?

Comment: Hello. Isn't it a kind of duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/40060/16495 ?

Comment: NO, I like something like this http://www.koenig-dl.com/course-calendar.aspx

Comment: Well, they certainly looks similar :) Hope answer to that older one will be helpful for you and provide a bit of guidance.

Comment: I dont get my answer from it , I found this very useful http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions/8979/how-do-i-create-view-product-table-variations  , but I have problem in contextual filter ( I cant see video because band width limit and low speed ). can u explain more how can I create a block that show product variation in product display content type?

Comment: Sadly, no. And I didn't vote to close as a duplicate, I just remembered I have seen something similar, so I asked in first comment. Sorry to hear it wasn't helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras) for this. It gives you the ability to add an add-to-cart checkbox on a Product view so that you can add one or more products to the cart. You can [see a demo of that functionality](https://drupalcommerce.org/blog/13680/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-add-cart-extras).

Comment: There is also a video we did at Commerce Guys that walks you through setting this up for a pretty standard product display: https://youtu.be/x7SRieMp0Bk?t=2m40s

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a view with base table "Commerce product. "

   1. Add necessary fields. Title, Price, Add to cart form, etc will be essential.
   2. Add Relationship "Commerce Product: Referencing Node".
   3. Add Contextual filter "Content: Nid". This view will list the products referenced by a product display node.
2. Install module [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield).
3. Add a view field to the product display content type, and set the view created in the first step as default value. Give `[node:nid]` as argument.
4. Configure the node display as you please.